# Specific code of choosing dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help. The table which I have to manupulate is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcVwVHkHN8SQ0thcUJwa2QwNjg/edit?usp=sharing 
What I want to do:

1. If rest of each account is changed I want to record it as in right part of the sheet, if for accNumber 123 (say, there are five accounts with accNumber 123), 'Rest' for first 3 entries (ordred by date) is 777, and their dates are 12/01/2013, 15/01/2013, 18/01/2013; and the 'Rest' values for the other 2 entries is 888, with dates 19/01/2013 and 29/01/2013. Since 'Rest' have changed on the third entry, the record should be accNumber (333), Rest (777), Date1 (12/01/2013), Date2 (19/01/2013). So, Date1 is minimum date with the same 'Rest' value, and Date2 is the minimum date of the next coming'Rest' value.
2. 'Rest' value of 888 is last (if ordered by date (desc)), so we have to record this also by assigning Date1 the minimum date of of this 'Rest' value, and to 'Date2' the maximum value of date of this particular 'Rest' value, not the minumum date of upcoming rest value (since there is no such).

Sorry, for such complicated question, I hope you understood. Here is what I wrote for the first part (it works). thanks in advance

```
select a.accNumber, a.Rest, min(a.Date),  min(b.Date)  
from tt1  a, tt1 b 
where b.Date>a.Date
and a.accNumber=b.accNumber
and a.Rest<>b.Rest
Group by a.accNumber, a.Rest
```

Comment: Please provide formatted sample data in your question and the expected output. Help us help you. Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: I am using MS SQL. I don't have any sample output. I have explained the question as clear as I can. But probably it's too hard to explain in way that users can understand. Sorry. but I would apppreciate any suggestion